# Most efficient way to download array of remote file URLs in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, client-server

I'm working on a Node project where I have an array of files such as

```
var urls = ["http://web.site/file1.iso", "https://web.site/file2.pdf", "https://web.site/file3.docx", ...];
```

I'm looking to download those files locally in the most efficient way possible. There could be as many as several dozen URLs in this array... Is there a good library that would help me abstract this out? I need something that I can call with the array and the desired local directory to that will follow redirects, work with http & https, intelligently limit simultaneous downloads, etc.

Comment: I'd use nodes http/s request method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) is a lovely little library that brings `fetch` capability to node.  Since `fetch` returns a promise, managing parallel downloads is simple.  Here's an example:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const fs = require('fs')

// You can expand this array to include urls are required
const urls = ['http://web.site/file1.iso', 'https://web.site/file2.pdf']

// Here we map the list of urls -> a list of fetch requests
const requests = urls.map(fetch)

// Now we wait for all the requests to resolve and then save them locally
Promise.all(requests).then(files => {
  files.forEach(file => {
    file.body.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('PATH/FILE_NAME.EXT'))
  })
})
```

Alternatively, you could write each file as it resolves:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const fs = require('fs')

const urls = ['http://web.site/file1.iso', 'https://web.site/file2.pdf']

urls.map(file => {
  fetch(file).then(response => {
    response.body.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('DIRECTORY_NAME/' + file))
  })
})
```